# Can not reach 100% Pester Code Coverage due to Script block

Tags: powershell, pester

Hi All,

I have been struggling a long time because of my pester not reaching 100% code coverage due to a scriptblock. I have been researching and reading articles to no success and I have decided to ask some help from you guys. :)

Part of the code I want to describe contains a scriptblock and would later be fed to a cmdlet Invoke-Command. Sample code below:

```
function Get-Function {
.....
Set-Alias Start-PowerShell32 $env:computername\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$ScriptBlock = { 
    Start-PowerShell32 -noprofile { 
        $sample = Get-Content -Path "C:\sample.txt
        Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Software"

        @($sample) | Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Stopped' }
        }
    }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
}

Describe Get-Function {
....
function Get-Statistics {

    Start-PowerShell32 -noprofile { 
        $sample = Get-Content -Path "C:\sample.txt
        Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Software"

        @($sample) | Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Stopped' }
        }
}
Context '1st Context'{
mock Set-Alias {'Setting alias for Powershell 32 bit'} -Verifiable
mock Get-Statistics {'Getting Statistics ....'} -Verifiable
mock Invoke-Command {Get-Statistics} -Verifiable
$result = Get-Function

    it 'should return etting alias for Powershell 32 bit'{
        $result[0] | should be "Setting alias for Powershell 32 bit"
        }
    it 'should return Getting Mailbox Statistics ....'{
        $result[1] | should be "Getting Statistics ...."
        }
    it 'should call all verifiable mocks'{
        Assert-VerifiableMocks
        }
    }
}
```

What I did on my Pester is that I made a custom function inside my Describe block(Get-Statistics) which is basically the inside of the script block for it to be called whenever I mock Invoke-Command to be Get-Statistics. My Pester succeeds but code coverage does not give me 100%.

Can you guys enlighten me on how to do this? do I need to change my tests? 

Thank You

Comment: You should be mocking `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Hi

I did mocked my invoke-command inside my first Context.

Comment: Your mock is bad.  It's never calling the inside scriptblock so it'd be impossible to achieve 100% coverage.

Comment: Does this mean I have two mocks for Invoke-Command?

Comment: I think your mock will be replaced by whatever is defined last in the lowest-scope possible

Comment: Ah 

tried it, but still i can not achieve 100% code coverage. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the head of your `Describe {` block, include a mock for `Invoke-Command`:

```
Describe '..' {
    Mock Invoke-Command { Param($SB) . $SB }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the tip. I have been experimenting using the above workaround and now I can achieve 100% code coverage with my pester.